# Call procedure or funcion passing a pair of value in array parameter

Tags: delphi

I need to pass a pair of value in array parameter function.

It is possible to call this form?

Call

```
Resul:= Validate( ['Johni', 18], ['Douglas', 22], ['Marangon', 19], [Dani, 29] )
```

Implementation

```
function Validate( /* Here, include pair array parameter */ ): Boolean
begin
  // Implemetation  
end;
```

The solution find.

```
TData = record
  Name: string;
  Age: Integer; 
  cosntructor Add( const AName: string; const AAge: Integer );
end;

cosntructor TData.Add( const AName: string; const AAge: Integer );
begin
  Name:= AName
  Age:= AAge;
end;

function Validate( const Array of TData ): Booelan;
begin
  // implemtation
end;

Result:= Validate( [ TData.Add( 'Johni', 18 ), TData.Add('Douglas', 22), TData.Add('Marangon', 19) TData.Add(Dani, 29) ] );
```

Thank you.

Comment: The example you have provided `TData.Add` is the best that can be achieved. Though I would prefer the name `Init` for the method. If using an older version of Delphi that does not support record methods a simple: `function InitTData(const AName: string; const AAge: Integer): TData` works just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use array notation to construct records. Array notation only constructs arrays and sets. Instead, you might take inspiration from the `Point` or `Rect` functions and make a standalone function that builds `TData` instances:

```
function Data(const Name: string; Age: Integer): TData;
begin
  Result.Name := Name;
  Result.Age := Age;
end;
```

It would give you more concise notation than calling methods of the `TData` type:

```
Validate([Data('Johni', 18), Data('Douglas', 22), Data('Marangon', 19),
          Data(Dani, 29)]);
```